# Question closed without consultation. Unhappy with linked question/answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question on Super User, it was migrated to 'Web Applications' and then linked with another question and closed as a duplicate.

I'm not happy with the answers provided in the linked question and would like [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/delete-old-facebook-wall-posts) made available again for any possible solutions (I would think that six months after the other answer was asked more options would be available).

Can I reopen my question AND leave it open?

(I would ask it again, but I'm fearing someone will close it again without consulting me).

Answer (score 6):

If the answers on the other question truly don't solve your problem, you should edit your closed question to add a reference to that question and explain why the answers there are no good. Then vote to re-open and, possibly, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 6):

The question asked is indeed a *possible* duplicate of [Script or App to remove own Facebook status updates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8989/script-or-app-to-remove-own-facebook-status-updates), but you are right, the answer given does not necessarily help the everyday Facebook user. You would need to edit your question to address a simple solution that does not involve programming.

The linked question : [Tool to bulk remove Facebook status updates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/tool-to-bulk-remove-facebook-status-updates) has an answer stating iMacros can help. You currently cannot vote to reopen your question, as you would need 250 reputation. Edit well and users in the community will come along and vote to reopen the question.

See also these related questions before editing your question,

- [How to delete all Facebook posts/comments older than 1 year?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/how-to-delete-all-facebook-posts-comments-older-than-1-year)
- [How to wipe out everything from your Facebook wall?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10136/how-to-wipe-out-everything-from-your-facebook-wall)